# How to add images dynamically in AS3?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, containers

Ok, i want to add a series of images, and then be able to drag and drop each one of them. I have all of my images embedded in a class Images. s0,s1,s2 are instances of image classes. Now this is what i've done

```
public function Main():void 
{
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

    function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        var a:Array = new Array(); 
        var imageContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;
        var imgClass:Images = new Images(); 

       for (var i:int = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            a[i].push(imgClass.(s+String(i)));
            imageContainer.addChild[a[i]]; 
        }
        stage.addChild(imageContainer);
        imageContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, takeIt);
        imageContainer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dropIt);

        function takeIt(event:MouseEvent) {
            event.currentTarget.startDrag(); 
        }
        function dropIt(event:MouseEvent) {
            event.currentTarget.stopDrag(); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have rewritten your code a bit, but I have not been able to test it sorry.

The first think I notices is that your `init` method was inside your `Main` method. Then your `takeIt` and `dropIt` method were inside the `init`. I am not to sure if that would actually work, but I have fixed it up in the code below.

In my code I assume that the image instances you have in the `Images` class are instances of `Bitmap`. This means that inside the `for` loop I had to add each one to a `Sprite` so you have access to `startDrag` and `stopDrag`. I listen for the `MOUSE_DOWN` event on each image, and set the image to the `selectedImage` var and do startDrag. I also listen for the `MOUSE_UP` on the `stage`, and drop the currentImage.

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class  Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var selectedImage:Sprite;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var imageContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();
            var imgClass:Images = new Images(); 

            for (var i:int = 0; i < 9; i++) 
            {
                var imgInstance:Bitmap = imgClass['s' + i.toString()] as Bitmap;
                var imgSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
                imgSprite.addChild(imgInstance); // Put image in a sprite so we can use startDrag on it.
                imageContainer.addChild(imgSprite);
                imgInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, img_mouseDownHandler);
            }

            addChild(imageContainer);

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseUpHandler);
        }

        private function dropSelectedImage():void 
        {
            if (selectedImage) 
            {
                selectedImage.stopDrag(); 
            }
        }

        private function img_mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            dropSelectedImage();
            selectedImage = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
            selectedImage.startDrag();
        }

        private function stage_mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void 
        {
            dropSelectedImage();
        }
    }
}
```

To build your images in a loop you could also just manually build the array, then loop through the array like so:

```
var images:Array = [imgClass.s0, imgClass.s1, imgClass.s2, imgClass.s3, imgClass.s4, imgClass.s5, imgClass.s6, imgClass.s7, imgClass.s8];
for each (var img:Bitmap in images) 
{
    var imgSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    imgSprite.addChild(img); // Put image in a sprite so we can use startDrag on it.
    imageContainer.addChild(imgSprite);
    imgInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, img_mouseDownHandler);
}
```

Hope this help. Feel free to ask me to elaborate or explain anything else in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tested your code. Images appear, but stop and start drag doesn't seem to work. Also, can you explain a bit why have you used imgSprite and imgContainer because imgSprite is a container of it's own ...

Comment: I set it up so each image is in it's own imgSprite. This is so you can use `startDrag` and `stopDrag` for each image (Bitmap does not have these methods). But there is only one imgContainer that contains ALL the images. You might not need the imgContainer, but it keeps things organised.

Comment: Ok, i changed your code: instead of setting event listener on imgInstance i set it on imgSprite and the code now works fine :) thanks for the help...